# Script not changing AD password settings based on CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

got a powershell script that has to use First and Last Name from CSV to do some password settings.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$Users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\users-to-reset.csv"

ForEach ($User in $Users) {
    $LastName = $User.LastName
    $FirstName = $User.FirstName

    $User = Get-ADUser -Filter 'surname -eq $LastName -and givenName -eq $FirstName'
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User -PasswordNeverExpires:$false
    Set-ADUser -Identity $User -CannotChangePassword:$false
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, don't re-use the `$User` in foreach loop and get-aduser. Second, check that the filter returns desired user account.

Comment: As @vonPryz says, but also by using single quotes around your filter, the variables in there won't get expanded. Do `$AdUser = Get-ADUser -Filter "Surname -eq '$LastName' -and GivenName -eq '$FirstName'"`. Then **test** if you indeed found a user (or perhaps multiple...) and only then use `Set-ADUser -Identity $AdUser ...`. Overall, it would be a lot better if you can use a more unique (at least withing the same domain)user property to filter the correct user like DistinguishedName, SamAccountName, EmailAddress or UserPrincipalName.

Answer (score -1):

In the past, I have just used [Set-ADAccountPassword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-adaccountpassword?view=windowsserver2022-ps) and [Set-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/set-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to do this.

```
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity $user -Reset -NewPassword $pw
```

I just used the -ChangePasswordAtLogon and -PasswordNeverExpires flags like this:

```
Set-ADUser -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Identity $($user.samAccountname) -Confirm:$false
```